# Rubber cloth preset looks wrinkled on character mesh

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

I have 3 objects (one character and two primitive objects) and I assigned cloth simulation with rubber preset (to achieve soft body simulation on self collision) to each of them with exactly the same settings. But when I run simulation character object looks wrinkled. What is the issue here? Why isn't it still? It should get wrinkled on self collision like e.g. when foot touch backpack and backpack get distorted.
[image: before rubber distortion]
[image: after rubber distortion]

Settings:
[image: rubber distortion settings]

Vertex group 'Group' is whole object mesh and weight is set to 0.

Comment: The other two objects have very clean edges, while your character mesh is more complex.   You might try increasing the detail (in EDIT mode of the character, Subdivide the faces several times), and/or perhaps add a smooth modifier to come before the cloth modifier in the stack -- above the cloth modifier.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is - less vertices = more solid.

I would say your topology in that place self collides. Current self-collision distance cause overlapping a space of several faces in their Normal direction.

Try to lower *Physics Properties > Cloth > Collision > Self Collisions >* **Distance**

[image]

Default Sphere with 0.004

[image]

... but lower value probably make it easier to penetrate.

Or you can try to use a Vertex Group (use vertices without "frame" part so it would be excluded from self-collision), but that is probably that you don't want to ... it defence own situation.

BTW There isn't a reason for *Shape > Pin Group*, when set zero - pinning doesn't take any effect.